# Galois Extension of Even Order

Tags: galois-theory

Suppose $E=F(\alpha)$ is a proper Galois extension. Let $\sigma \in Gal(E/F)$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha^{-1}$. Show that $[E:F]$ is even and $[F(\alpha + \alpha^{-1}):F]=\frac{1}{2} [E:F]$.

I was wondering that if $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ then is the reciprocal polynomial the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^{-1}$?

Comment: Any thoughts? Tried anything? Consider $F(\alpha+\alpha^{-1})=E^{\langle\sigma\rangle}$. The answer to your question about minimal polynomials is yes (can you prove it?).

Comment: If g(x) is the reciprocal polynomial then if g(x)=g_1(x).g_2(x) such that deg(g_1)+deg(g_2)=deg(f) then f(x)=x^{n}g(\frac{1}{x})=x^p g_1(\frac{1}{x})x^q g_2(\frac{1}{x}). where p=deg(g_1) and q=deg(g_2). This contradicts the irreducibility of f(x)?

Comment: Notice that $\LaTeX$ doesn't work when you don't put dollar signs around it...

Comment: If g(x) is the reciprocal polynomial then if g(x)=$g_1(x).g_2(x)$ such that deg$(g_1)$+deg$(g_2)$=deg(f) then $f(x)=x^{n}g(\frac{1}{x})=x^p g_1(\frac{1}{x})x^q g_2(\frac{1}{x})$. where p=deg$(g_1)$ and q=deg$(g_2)$. This contradicts the irreducibility of f(x)?

Comment: I just don't see how $F(\alpha + \alpha^{-1})$ is the fixed field of $<\sigma>$

Comment: Oh okay I see it! $\sigma(\alpha + \alpha^{-1})=\sigma(\alpha)+(\sigma(\alpha))^{-1}=\alpha^{-1}+\alpha$

Comment: That's part of it, yes. I am actually not sure at the moment if the result holds in positive characteristic. Can we assume characteristic zero for convenience?

Comment: Well the characteristic of the field is not mentioned in the problem. But I guess we could.

Comment: I don't think that the characteristic of the field matters at all.

Comment: Zeus: Yes, your argument with reciprocal polynomials is the way to do that part.

Answer (score 1):

Extended hints/steps:

Let $K$ be the fixed field of $\sigma$, and let $L=F(\alpha+\alpha^{-1})$.

1. Show that $\sigma$ is of order two  (assuming "proper extension" means that $F$ is a proper subfield of $E$).
2. Show that $[E:K]=2$.
3. Show that as $E=L(\alpha)$, we also have $[E:L]\le2$.
4. Show that $L\subseteq K$.
5. Show that $L=K$.